# What can I put inside a 39mm gel holder?

Tags: lens, filters, gels

### Context

So I have a 39mm gel holder for my Nikon 300 f4. AF lens. 
[image: Filter]

### Question

What can I put inside it? It doesn't look like a normal filter will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In lighting terms, a *gel* is a piece of thin, transparent, plasticky material in the color of your choosing. [Rosco](https://www.rosco.com) and [LEE](http://www.leefilters.com) are perhaps the best known gel manufacturers, at least in the US. Gels come in large sheets that you cut down to fit your application. One 20"x24" sheet of a given color will probably last a lifetime if you're only using it in your gel holder, but they're also not very expensive at around $7 or $8 for a sheet of [Rosco Cinegel](https://www.rosco.com/filters/cinegel.cfm?menuReturn=photo).

Comment: Years ago when I first heard of gel filters, I used to imagine someone smearing a Vaseline-like substance on the front of lenses/lights! This explanation of gels isn't new to me now, but should be helpful for others.

Comment: Never used one but that explanation definitely helps.

Comment: Those aren't true gelatin filters, those are cellophane 'gels'.

Answer (score 4):

A gel filter cut to a circle slightly larger than 39mm in diameter is what the holder is designed to hold. There should be a flap that opens up and lets you insert the filter material. You then close the flap back over the filter material to hold it in place.

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know that opened. I presume a gel, in this context, is a sheet that I buy, cut and fit in?